# How can send sms by url codeigntor

Tags: codeigniter

http://52.36.50.145:8080/MainServlet?orgName=XXX&userName=XXX&password=XXX&mobileNo=967777662112&text=
msg + "&coding=2"

I have that's url how can send  send sms by for mulit user codeigntor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You must use `cURL` in `CodeIgniter`. this function works fine for **Sending SMS**.*

```
function sms_code_send($number='',$message='')
    {
    $username   = 'username';
    $password   = '*******';
    $originator = 'sender name';
    $message    = 'Welcom to ......, your activation code is : '.$message;
    //set POST variables
    $url = 'http://exmaple.com/bulksms/go?';

    $fields = array(
      'username'   => urlencode($username),
      'password'   => urlencode($password),
      'originator' => urlencode($originator),
      'phone'      => urlencode($number),
      'msgtext'    => urlencode($message)
     );

    $fields_string = '';

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    {
      $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }

    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```